# Deleting a discussion from a discussion board

Tags: 2016, discussion-board

Does anyone know how to delete a discussion from a discussion board SharePoint 2016?  I have posted a question and now want to remove it

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the [permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200443/discussion-board-list-unlike-other-lists-will-not-allow-contributor-users-to-del) are set. Create and Edit Access have to be set to allow users to delete their own discussion. Once that's done, you should be able to go into the discussion, click on the ellipses and select Delete.